# Remove Socket.IO emitter on disconnect from EventEmitter attatched event array of functions

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io

I have EventEmitter and socket.io working in tandem and they work as I am expecting them to work. I have an object, that contains data, that data can randomly change at any point in time, when the data changes, it fires an EventEmitter.emit with the updated data.

In another file I have an EventEmitter.on which captures that data and passes it on to socket.emit to be sent to the front end, something like this:

Within the object containing the data:

```
UpdateIfDataIsNew(newData, oldData) {
  if (newData !== oldData) { //simplified, not exactly like this
    eventBus.emit('dataEvent', newData)
  }
}
```

Where eventBus is a global EventEmitter object.

And in my file handling the sending of the data to the front end, the code is roughly:

```
ioServer.on("connection", (socket) => {
  eventBus.on("dataEvent", (data) => {
    socket.emit("frontEndDataEvent", data);
  });
})
```

The way that this is working, whenever a new user connects, a new socket is created, and a new socket.emit is added to the list of functions to be fired when "dataEvent" is triggered, so that all connected users receive the updated data. The problem is that I don't know how to remove a particular socket.emit from the eventBus array of functions when a particular user disconnects, because when I don't do that, all functions stay in the event array, and all of them fire when an event is triggered, althought these users are no longer on the website, eventually the array gets incredibly big, even a simple refresh from a single user, keeps adding more and more functions to the array.

I know that I can see if a user has disconnected with `socket.on("disconnect", ???)` but then what?

http://prntscr.com/tou4pw the functions are the same, just with a different socket, how do I find the one that must be removed, when someone disconnects?

Instead of just adding a function to the eventEmitter, can I add say an object that contains an ID: and the function, so that I can then quickly identify the one that I must remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating my own Event Emitter class (externding EventEmitter), that way I have control over the array of functions for a given event and am also able to assign an ID.

```
const EventEmitter = require("events");

class RobotData extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.emitters = [];
  }

  add(socket, dataType) {
    this.emitters.push({
      socket,
      dataType,
      trigger: (eventName, newData) => {
        socket.emit(`${eventName}`, newData);
      },
    });
  }

  remove(ID) {
    this.emitters = this.emitters.filter((emitter) => emitter.socket.id !== ID);
  }
}

const robotData = new RobotData();

module.exports = { robotData };
```

And then in the disconnect event:

```
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  robotData.remove(socket.id);
});
```